# Does copying for hours wear the hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

I got a new harddrive where I want to backup a lot of my old files. Is it a bad idea to copy (rsync) all files in one chunk and let it run for a day. Or is it better to copy in smaller bursts.

Does it wear on the harddisk if I copy straight for ~24+ hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In electronics, it's known as infant mortality.

If it's going to be damaged by normal use, it'll probably die in the first month.

Otherwise it will live out the normal lifespan with no problems at all.

Better to find out early on, I've always found.

If it doesn't give out in your 24 hour run, you've got a good one that will give you 5-6 years of reliable service. The drives produced now are so much more reliable that your proposed one chunk copy won't damage them.

We used to do exactly this kind of operation for a day or two to burn in server drives back when they were likely to have manufacturer's defects.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little in it, but it is probably better to copy it all at once - fewer starts and stops means less dramatic head movement.  Also less reads from rsync.   Also (and this may not be an issue depending on your hardware/software), if you have power saving on, starts and stops will spin up and spin down the disk creating inrush current every time it starts, which puts more wear on the disk.

I note that most RAID devices will start rebuilding immediately they are set up, there is no delay or cooling off period where its done in bits.

The only "concern" might be heat buildup of the disk, but if cooling is good, its theoretically better to keep the disk spinning so the heat is constant rather then heat & cool which leads to expansion and contraction and more wear and tear.

In summary - its marginally better to copy it all at once, but it should not make a discernible difference on the drive unless the drive is faulty.